# How can I determine the version of a remote NFS share?

Tags: linux, nfs, network-share, nfs4

I am having trouble with a some software, that only can mount NFSv3 and NFSv4 share - it can not mount NFSv4.1 or NFSv4.2.

Since I do not have access to the server itself, I cannot determine what exact version of NFS is being used.

I am aware of the rpcinfo command:

```
rpcinfo -p server
```

which print out the version of the shares like this:

```
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
      7507    1   tcp   7507
    100024    1   udp  20049  status
    100024    1   tcp  20049  status
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100021    4   tcp  20050  nlockmgr
```

Or the following:

```
rpcinfo -u server nfs 3
rpcinfo -t server nfs 4
```

That prints:

```
program 100003 version 3 ready and waiting
```

and

```
program 100003 version 4 ready and waiting
```

However, how do I determine in NFSv4.1 or NFSv4.2 is being used by the server from the client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nfsstat -m

Watch out for “vers” inside the reported flags.